# How to Add different name spaces to XML payload using XSLT

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I have a simple a XML Payload request, I need to add mutiple namespaces. I have tried a lot but with any luck. Could you help how to transform the XML request,

Payload

```
<insert>
    <u_email_domain>Test.eu</u_email_domain>
    <u_cost_center>costcenter123</u_cost_center>
    <u_department>ItDepartment</u_department>
    <u_family_name>Donald</u_family_name>
    <u_first_name>Trump</u_first_name>
    <u_foreseen_end_date/>
    <u_hris_id>1000091</u_hris_id>
    <u_job_title>Manager</u_job_title>
    <u_location>newyork</u_location>
    <u_manager_hris_id>10000421</u_manager_hris_id>
    <u_notification_recipients>dummy@email.com</u_notification_recipients>
    <u_vip>NO</u_vip>
</insert>
```

Expected Result

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://www.service-now.com/u_hr_is">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <u:insert>
                <u:u_email_domain>Test.eu</u:u_email_domain>
                <u:u_cost_center>costcenter123</u:u_cost_center>
                <u:u_department>ItDepartment</u:u_department>
                <u:u_family_name>Donald</u:u_family_name>
                <u:u_first_name>Trump</u:u_first_name>
                <u:u_hris_id>1000091</u:u_hris_id>
                <u:u_job_title>Manager</u:u_job_title>
                <u:u_location>newyork</u:u_location>
                <u:u_manager_hris_id>10000421</u:u_manager_hris_id>
                <u:u_vip>NO</u:u_vip>
        </u:insert>
    </soapenv:Body>`enter code here`
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
Try this:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/insert">

    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://www.service-now.com/u_hr_is">
      <soapenv:Body>
        <u:insert>
          <u:u_email_domain>
            <xsl:value-of select="u_email_domain"/>
          </u:u_email_domain>
          <u:u_cost_center>
            <xsl:value-of select="u_cost_center"/>
          </u:u_cost_center>
          <u:u_department>
            <xsl:value-of select="u_department"/>
          </u:u_department>
          <u:u_family_name>
            <xsl:value-of select="u_family_name"/>
          </u:u_family_name>
          <u:u_first_name>
            <xsl:value-of select="u_first_name"/>
          </u:u_first_name>
          <u:u_hris_id>
            <xsl:value-of select="u_hris_id"/>
          </u:u_hris_id>
          <u:u_job_title>
            <xsl:value-of select="u_job_title"/>
          </u:u_job_title>
          <u:u_location>
            <xsl:value-of select="u_location"/>
          </u:u_location>
          <u:u_manager_hris_id>
            <xsl:value-of select="u_manager_hris_id"/>
          </u:u_manager_hris_id>
          <u:u_vip>
            <xsl:value-of select="u_vip"/>
          </u:u_vip>
        </u:insert>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```